# SetInterval is not working in javascript after sometime when its called a function for a perticular time interval

Tags: javascript, php, timer

This is my html code, onclick event calling the:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onclick="click_function()"/>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Upon clicking of button, the below script loads the data by calling the function for every one minute if the data came from the server the setinterval will stops calling the function, until the data is created in the server the function will call the `check()` function if the data is present then it will display the data.

```
<script>
function click_function() {

    var ajax_load = "<img id='loading' src='loader.gif' alt='loading...' />";
    $("#display").html(ajax_load);

    check_interval();

    function check_interval() {
        var set_inter = setInterval(function(){
            check();
        }, 60000);

    function check(){
        if($("#display").val=="") {
            $("#display").html(ajax_load);
        } else {
            $("#display").html(ajax_load).load("get_test.php",{},function(){});
            clearInterval(set_inter);
        }
    }
</script>
```

But when I run the script for every 1 minute the function will refresh the other function, the setinterval is not working and stopping the whole script after the second minute.

I got an error message:

[image]

> Something went wrong while displaying the webpage,To continue,reload or go to another page.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your code like this:

```
var set_inter = null;

function click_function(){

    var ajax_load = "<img id='loading' src='loader.gif' alt='loading...' />";
    $("#display").html(ajax_load);

    check_interval();
}

function check_interval(){

    set_inter =  setInterval(function(){
        check();
    }, 60000);
}

function check(){

    if($("#display").val==""){

        $("#display").html(ajax_load);
    }else{

        $("#display").html(ajax_load).load("get_test.php",{},function(){});
        clearInterval(set_inter);
    }
}
```

It was a problem with scopes at first and you need to make variable set_inter global to use in other function.

Comment: I have another question, is the div  if($("#display").val=="")  is empty than it should load the indicator and it has to call the function setinterval, checking the div is empty is correct only!! ?

Comment: And also i put the variable global and the same error is getting, please suggest with another code